# Retrieve values along a streamline in mayavi

Tags: mayavi

I have a velocity field and a density profile defined by `vx`, `vy`, and `vz`, and dens. All of these variable are 3D arrays, e.g.

```
vx.shape
(256,256,256)
```

same for `vy`, `vz`, and `dens`.

The flow command works properly e.g.

```
fl = flow(vx,vy,vz, seedtype='point', integration_direction='both', scalars=dens)
```

and I can visualise the field line. Now, to retrieve the values of `vx,vy,vz` and `dens` at the positions x,y,z along the line what I did in the past (a few years ago with a previous version of mayavi, I suppose) was

```
dataset = fl.outputs[0]
```

then

```
x, y, z = dataset.points.to_array().T
densstream = np.array(dataset.point_data.get_array(0))
vstream = np.array(dataset.point_data.get_array(1))
```

But running

```
x, y, z = dataset.points.to_array().T
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'AlgorithmOutput' object has no attribute 'points'.

Typing

```
dataset
```

I get

```
<tvtk.tvtk_classes.algorithm_output.AlgorithmOutput at 0x1132917d0>
```

I am using a mac OS 10.12.6, Python 2.7.15 and IPython 5.5.0.
Could you help me, please?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of mayavi have modified the output ports for some tvtk objects, from the older version's `tvtk.obj.output` into `tvtk_obj.output_port`. The latter is a algorithm_output subclass of tvtk and does not contain the point data, which is the reason for the error message.

In mayavi/modules/streamline.py, the method _streamline_type_changed(self, value):
updates the output port of the streamline object via `configure_outputs(self, st)`, a method of tvtk/common.py, but the connection is directed to `self.stream_tracer.output_port` instead of `self.stream_tracer.output`. And the latter is the correct poly_data subclass and does contain the point data along the streamline.
So the cure is simply:

```
dataset = fl.stream_tracer.output
```

By the way, I've also tried modifying the function call into `configure_outputs(self, st.output)`, although `fl.outputs[0]` is connected correctly to the poly_data output, yet the streamlines are no longer shown in the mayavi scene.

Comment: Dear @ArcherEX, thank you very much for your help. Now it perfectly works as with the previous versions of mayavi! Cheers